# Create hanami project?

Tags: ruby, bundler, hanami

With hanami 2.0.1 and ruby version 3.0.2...
When create hanami new bookshelf.I got this error..

```
Created bookshelf/
-> Within bookshelf/
Created .env
Created README.md
Created Gemfile
Created Rakefile
Created config.ru
Created config/app.rb
Created config/settings.rb
Created config/routes.rb
Created config/puma.rb
Created lib/tasks/.keep
Created lib/bookshelf/types.rb
Created app/actions/.keep
Created app/action.rb
Running Bundler install...
`bundle install' failed


"install: unknown option -- jobs=2\nTry 'install --help' for more information."
```

I use bundle install but still ................
cd bookshelf and run bundle install,It's worked
but when

> bundle exec hanami server

```
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:308:in `block in replace_bin_path': can't find executable guard for gem guard. guard is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile? (Gem::Exception)
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:336:in `block in replace_bin_path'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
```

Add gem 'guard' into Gemfile.

```
 No Guardfile exists at Guardfile. (Guard::Guardfile::Evaluator::NoCustomGuardfile)
```

Comment: do other bundle install also fail ? for example, if you set up a sinatra project, does the command fail ?

Comment: I don't think you need to do `bundle install`. The commands are : `hanami new blabla` then `cd blabla` and `hanami server`. Gems are already installed.

Comment: I assume it’s 2.0.1, not 2.1. Unless you did the work for us 

Comment: by the way, when is 2.1 due? I'm eager to start :)

Answer (score 1):

From the root of your app, run `bundle exec hanami install`.